# Безлично-инфинитивные предложения

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

В статье https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/bezlichno-infinitivnye-predlozheniya-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke
перечисляется порядка сотни однотипных примеров безлично-инфинитивных предложений, сводящихся примерно к одному:

```
Ему было нечем заняться.
```

Но не дается ни одного примера типа

```
Ему было чем заняться.
```

Получается, что два практически одинаковых предложения относятся к разным типам? На основании чего такая странная классификация? Отмечу что **чем** не является союзным словом. Во-первых, нельзя вставить парное указательное местоимение (Ему было то/тем(???), чем заняться). Во-вторых, запятые никто не ставит (судя по нацкорпусу), а перед союзным словом они должны ставиться.

И еще вопросик. Правильно ли я провел разбор предложений?

```
Ему было нечем заняться. // сказуемое = было. дополнение к было = заняться. дополнение к заняться = нечем.
Ему было чем заняться. // сказуемое = было. дополнение к было = заняться. дополнение к заняться = чем.
```

Comment: Попробуйте разобрать предложение без «было»: _Ему нечем заняться._  Разве в нём нет сказуемого? А если есть, то какое?

Comment: Без "было" во втором предложении не получится. Там обязательно "было/есть": "Ему есть чем заняться". Что касается первого предложения "Ему нечем заняться", то можно было бы записать его совсем в другой тип - обычные инфинитивные предложения, так как там нет связки было(хотя есть дтив. Но если настаивать, что она там "нулевая" или "опциональная" ("Ему (есть) определенно нечем заняться") , то можно было бы сказать что у нас составное глагольное сказуемое - заняться с потенциальной связкой "быть". Проблема в том что связка быть используется в именных сказуемых, а не в глагольных. Странно все это.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Теория безлично-инфинитивных предложений**  вполне ясно изложена в современной науке, в частности в книге Кустовой, которая давно уже предлагается в качестве учебного пособия для вузов. Там все понятно, все вполне логично и соответствует общему **семантико-грамматическому подходу** в изучении синтаксиса.

Г.И. Кустова и др. Синтаксис современного русского языка. Рекомендовано в качестве учебного пособия для студентов высших учебных заведений, обучающихся по специальности  Русский язык и литература  2005 год (также 2017, 2019), стр. 93.

2. У этих предложений трехчленная структура, то есть **три обязательных элемента** – инфинитив, местоимение и глагольная связка  (в настоящем времени — нулевая).  Все остальные члены предложения будут распространителями.

Безлично-инфинитивные предложения имеют **три основные формы:**

1. **отрицательную**: Нечего читать; Не о чем говорить; Незачем туда ехать; Не к кому обратиться; 2) **утвердительную:** Есть что читать; Есть о чем поговорить; Есть зачем ехать; Есть к кому обратиться;  3) **вопросительную:** Что нам было читать?; К кому нам было обратиться?

Для сравнения: в **инфинитивных предложениях** только один главный член (инфинитив) составляет структуру предложения, указание на субъекта **действия** туда не входит: Тебе ходить.

3. Таким образом,  можно только посмотреть, **как строится грамматическая трехчленная основа.**

Как я думаю, основным элементом является  **инфинитив**, при этом у него **назывная** функция:  он называет действие, а не выражает реальное действие, как в инфинитивных предложениях.

**Связка**  (в том числе нулевая) сближает эти предложения с **бытийными**, то есть обозначает **существование** (есть или нет), в случае со словом «нет» это будет безличный вариант (вода есть – воды нет).

Местоимение выполняет функцию **обязательного дополнения:**  есть что читать – нечего читать (есть  читать что – нет читать ничего).

Но такой разбор **не делается,** а просто называются три основных элемента грамматической основы. Например: ***Мне есть что читать***:  есть что читать – грамматическая основа, мне – дополнение, второстепенный член.

5. **Ваш разбор вызывает сомнение.**  В этих предложениях сказуемое не выделяется, да и говорится в них не о самом действии, а о **существовании** возможного действия (есть или нет).

***Ему было нечем заняться.***  Грамматическая основа: *было нечем заняться*:   *заняться* – название действия,  *было* – глагольная связка, *нечем* – дополнение.
***Ему было чем заняться.*** Грамматическая основа: *было чем заняться*:   *заняться* – название действия,  *было* – глагольная связка, *чем* – дополнение.

6. **У Розенталя эта тема также рассматривается**
   § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Цельные по смыслу выражения не отделяются и не выделяются запятыми:

**п. 7.** Внутри выражений типа:  ****есть чем заняться,*** есть над чем поработать, было о чём подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать, осталось на что жить*, **состоящих** из глагола ***быть***, или ***найти*** (найтись), или ***остаться,***  вопросительно-относительного **местоимения либо наречия** (кто, что, где, куда, когда и т. д.) и неопределенной формы другого **глагола**, запятая не ставится:

Тебе есть в мире что забыть (Л.); Бранить есть кому, кормить — некому (Даль); Есть чему и нравиться (Пис); И нашу интеллигенцию есть за что любить, есть за что уважать (М. Г.); Есть над чем задуматься; Нашли чем удивить; Не нашёлся что сказать; У нас будет чем козырнуть; Нашла где модничать; Есть когда с тобой болтать!; Было отчего приуныть; Друзьям есть о чём поговорить; Ребятам было где проводить свободное время; Нам было в чём упрекнуть его.

Comment: Любопытно, любопытно.
1. В двух статьях 2015 годов ни слова не говорится об утвердительных предложениях. Будто авторы не в курсе этого. 2. Не нашел у Кустовой про не выделение сказуемого. 3. Вот если бы приняли парадигму европейских языков, со сказуемым-глаголом и дополнением-глаголом, то не пришлось бы изобретать костыли в виде "сказуемые не выделяются, а просто называется трехзвенная основа".